# Как использовать scope system

Tags: java, maven

Как можно использовать *scope system*, Есть библиотека `jcoels-3.2.jar`, находится к примеру в диске `C:/libs`, что мне надо писать в `pom.xml` в dependency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот так:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jcoels</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcoels</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>C:\libs\jcoels-3.2.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Серьезно? Настоящий Барух Садогурский на русском stackoverflow?)

Comment: Зашел посмотреть как у вас тут и что. Уютненько, чо.